# Remove list from inside another list

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-lists

I would like to remove a list from inside another list. I have a list which looks like this:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

I would like the list to look like this, so it is only a singular list rather than nested:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: For this specific case, you can reassign to include only the inner list:  `mylist = mylist[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you can just access the zero index from original list.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a[0]
>>> b
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is :

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

then you can do like this

```
new_lst = lst[0]
```

You `new_lst` would be :

`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

If your **original lst** has many lists inside it like :

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],...]
```

Then you can do the following :

```
new_lst = []
for i in lst : 
    for j in i :
        new_lst.append(j)
```

So your `new_lst` would be :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...]
```

You could also do it in a shorthand notation as :

```
new_list = [element for sublist in lst for element in sublist]
```

The above snippet is exactly similar as previous one, just a **shorthand notation**